# PHP or Linux Shell: Fastest way to reduce a text file that has more than 10 lines to only have the last 10 lines

Tags: php, linux

I need to know the fastest way possible, in PHP or Linux Command Shell, to reduce a text file that has more than 10 lines to only have the last 10 lines. I want to use 10 lines for this example.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried to measure it with `time` on your shell?

Comment: Fastest way in terms of code length/complexity? Fastest runtime?

Comment: `tail [file]`. fastest thing around

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need that reduction to occure in that SAME file. I don't want to make another file.

Comment: the smaller the code the better :)

Comment: If you want to do it in the same file, then just use tail -n 10 path/to/file > path/to/file

Comment: @MikeBrant no, buddy, that won't work as it zero-bytes the file

Comment: @webdev Sorry, but you will not be able to do this reduction in the same file. Even if you were to use sed, you would still be operating on an internally created temp file. See http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to reduce a file to it's last then lines do

```
tail -n 10 /path/to/file > /path/to/file.tmp && rm /path/to/file && mv /path/to/file.tmp /path/to/file
```

explanation:

`tail` outputs the last `n` lines of a file.
`>` writes it to a file.
`&&` is for chaining commands.
`rm` removes a file.
`mv` renames a file (or moves to a different location).

Comment: You don't need the `-n 10` - tail defaults to 10 lines unless you say otherwise.

Comment: well he wanted to use 10 lines as an example. if we don't tell him he won't be able to use a different number ;)

Comment: Yeah, but since he's after a fast solution, this way you need to type 6 characters fewer.

Comment: @Radix - was that addressed to me?

Comment: i need a fast solution but at the same time i'd like to know a little of whats going on behind the code andrew. im still new to linux admin, so ty so much for adding that -n 10 andreas :)

Comment: okay big shot, do it in one file, as the OP has now commented :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really really don't want to generate a new file, then you might try

```
echo "$(tail -n 10 path/to/file)" >path/to/file
```

The `$()` works just like backticks (it evaluates whatever's inside and equates to the output of said command), except it works better in strings.  On my Linux machine, the string gets evaluated (meaning `tail` is run) before the output goes to the file (which is what causes the problems with `tail file >file`; the file gets opened -- and truncated -- as soon as the command starts).  <s>I'm thinking it's because `echo` is a builtin, but don't quote me on that.</s>

**EDIT:**  Actually, i took a closer look.  It's because the `tail` is in a string.  There are several phases -- here, the ones we care about are interpolation, redirection and execution -- that always happen in a certain defined order (namely, the order just given).   And in the process of interpolating the string, Bash has to run the command within it.  Before any redirection is done.  With a straight `tail file >file`, the `tail` program is what actually generates the output, so no output happens til the command is executed -- but the file's already been opened for writing (due to redirection) right before that, and opening that file for writing truncates it.)

```
phase          tail file >file                   echo "$(tail file)" >file
-------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------
interpolate   nothing                           run "tail file"; get output (+)
redirect      open file for write; set stdout   open file for write; set stdout
execute       run "tail file" (*)               run 'echo "line\nline\n..."'
```

`(*)`: Note, since `file` was already opened for writing by this point, it's now truncated.  So `tail` reads 0 bytes.
`(+)`: Since `file` was read in *before* the redirection opened it for writing, `tail` manages to see all the data.

Even though the behavior is obviously defined and predictable, this still feels kinda hacky to me.  It relies on bash arcana, and may very well cause memory issues if you try to get too many or too long lines.  (I tested with ~500 char lines, and didn't see any issues.  But haven't tested with more than 10 lines yet.)  It'd probably be better to use a temp file unless you need to preserve the same inode number for some odd reason.

Comment: where is the data of the last 10 lines stored O_o? is it in memory? Whichever method uses the least system resource. So if making a tmp file and then overwriting the original requires the least system work then I'd go with that. I want simplicity but also performance ;)

Comment: `"$(tail...)"` gets interpolated and becomes a string containing the entire output of the `tail` command.  Which, yeah.  Gets stored in memory temporarily.  It'll take more memory, but should be a tiny amount faster as it only has to mess with the file system once for input and once for output (rather than shuffling filenames around).  Still, a temp file feels more "safe" to me -- though unlike temp files, it's next to impossible for two strings in different processes to collide.  :)

Comment: that's a neat hack ;)  and thanks for warning me about the mem issue. It will be handy to retain the same file since I know when the file was made. Is there a way to make the original blank and copy the contents of the temp file onto the original file?

Comment: If you use a temp file, you could say `cat path/to/temp/file >path/to/file` to overwrite the original, and then `rm path/to/temp/file`.  But then you get all the downsides of temp files *plus* all the downsides of overwriting the original file.

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -n 10 yourfile > yourfile.tmp && mv yourfile.tmp yourfile
```

Edited to give exclusively the last 10 lines of a file with potentially greater than 10 lines.

Comment: well, mine and Mike Brant's certainly did solve the issue as ORIGINALLY stated.

Comment: this won't work as well, the file will be empty after that ^^

Comment: well you just copied my answer ;)

Comment: uh, no I did not -- there really is only one solution if using tmp file

Comment: sure this is why your answer twice changed to exactly what i wrote ;)

Answer (score 0):

In linux you could do

```
tail -n 10 path/to/file > path/to/output/file
```

This will take the last ten lines (# of lines specified by value after -n) of the file and then append them to another file.

If you want to overwrite the existing file with only its last ten lines then do

```
tail -n 10 path/to/file > path/to/output/file && mv path/to/output/file path/to/file
```

Note the first example outputs to a different file while the second overwrite the existing file.

You could also do this in PHP by using exec() with the shell command inside, or the more laborious way of reading the entire file into an array with file() and then taking the last ten elements of the array and adding them back into the file with fwrite() or similar.

Comment: @GabiPurcaru I didn't -1  but did just +1 it to even out for you :)

Comment: If you append the last 10 lines to the file, then every time you run this command the file will have up to 10 *extra* lines, rather than being trimmed down.  You want to use `>` rather than `>>`.

Comment: your answer `tail -n 10 path/to/file >> path/to/file` duplicates the last ten lines of the file ;)

Comment: @cHap Isn't that what he was asking to do?  Take the last ten lines and then add them back into the same file? Well I guess not since the question has now been edited.  Oh well.

Comment: No.  He's trying to make the file *only* contain the last 10 lines.

Comment: @cHao  His original question was stated much different and has since been edited. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Even with the original question...think it over to yourself.  Realize that when interpreted as the question you answered, it would be pretty useless.  Anyway, now that it's fixed, +1 :)

Comment: @cHao Sure it may have been useless in many cases, but what if he wanted to build a sample data file by quickly duplicating data in the file on top of itself or something similar.  The question was specifically stated as asking how to take ten lines from the end of a file and append them back to the SAME file. Note all the other answers above where everyone interpreted the question the exact same way.

Comment: @MikeBrant: No, he was asking how to take the last 10 lines and *write* them to the same file.  Not append.  If you want to give an overly literal answer, at least go all the way with it.

Comment: @MikeBrant can you believe the degree of attention we are giving this little question? :)

Comment: cHao is right in that I didn't need to explain since i already stated "Reduce a text file" NOT "Append a  text file" haha ;). I just edited it to state the SAME file only because all the answers were about appending and making new file haha. But I understand it's a habit to make new files as linux admins so I apologize if I wasn't clear enough ;)