# PHP or Linux Shell: Fastest way to reduce a text file to only have the last 10 characters

Tags: php, linux

I need the fastest way, in PHP or Linux Command Shell, to reduce a text file to only retain the last 10 characters. To be clear, I need the reduction to occur on that same file.

thanks :)

Comment: First it's [10 lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657509/php-or-linux-shell-fastest-way-to-reduce-a-text-file-that-has-more-than-10-line), now just 10 chars. Make up your mind?

Answer (score 4):

Shell `tail` command:

```
tail filename.txt --bytes 10 > filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PHP solution - however, if you don't want to do that from a PHP script better use the shell solution.

Seek to the end of the file minus 10 bytes (assuming one character is one byte) and then overwrite the file with the ten last characters:

```
$fp = fopen('filename', 'a');
fseek($fp, -10, SEEK_END);
$data = fread($fp, 10);
fclose($fp);
file_put_contents('filename', $data);
```

Comment: Your last line should be `$data`, not `$date`.

Comment: the way you've done this is actually quite efficient with `fseek()`, so if the OP wanted a pure PHP solution, then it would be a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is shorter :)

```
tail -c 10 filename.txt > filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To bring some diversity :)

```
dd if=./filename.txt of=./result.txt bs=1 skip=$((`wc -c < filename.txt`-11))
```